# $f:D(0,1)\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}$, holomorphic, given integrability criterion, show the bound of order of pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

It is an exercise of Conway, let $p\in(0,\infty)$, if $\int_{D(0,1)} |f|^p dA<\infty$. Then classify type of singularity.

I have a very rough idea but I do not know how to write it rigorously. Assume $f$ is meromorphic, say it has a pole of order $m$. Then $mp<2$ due to integrability.

On the other hand, I think it would not be an essential sigularity. However, I do not know how to get rid of the essential singularity possibiltiy. I was thinking by Casorati Weierstrass theorem, for all $M$ there exists neighbourhood $N_M$ of size $\delta_M$ s.t. $f(z)>M$ for all $z\in N_M$. However, the size of $\delta_M$, I don't know how to control. If it goes to zero, then I cannot draw a contradiction.

Thank you!

Comment: what? if $f$ is identically 0, for example, then there is no singularity?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but if f identically zero, then for sure there is removable singularity, or I would say pole of order $0$. But essential singularity is the case I wanna eliminate.

Comment: Subharmonicity of $|f|^p$ solves this problem.